# can you help me analyze this sentencce?

Tags: grammar

> 보기와 같이 ____에 들어갈 가장 알맞은 것을 고르싶시오

I know the general meaning,but I don't know how the part 들어갈 works,can you explain the sentence from grammatical perspective?

Answer (score 0):

> 보기와 같이 ____에 들어갈 가장 알맞은 것을 고르십시오 = Pick the most suitable one to go in ____ as shown in the example.

들어갈 is 들어가다 in the -(으)ㄹ ending form (it becomes 을 after a syllable ending with a consonant).  This ending represents 1) future
tense or what is expected to happen, or 2) tenseles noun-modifying form.

Here are examples of #1 meaning:

- 내가 해야할 일 = work for me to do / work that I have to do.
- 먹을 것이 없다 = There is nothing to eat.
- 세 시에 도착할 열차 = The train to arrive at three / The train that will arrive at three.

And for #2:

- 해가 질 때 = when the sun sets.
- 경쟁에서는 이길 때도 있고 질 때도 있다 = In competition, there are times that you win and times you lose.

In each of the examples, the -(으)ㄹ ending modifies a noun that follows it, like the to-infinitive phrase or a "that/which/when" clause in English.  It can create a future form (like "am/are/is to VERB", "will/would VERB") or an expectation or obligation ("work to do", "schedule to meet").

Comment: so 들어갈 modify 것?

Comment: Yes, both 들어갈 and 가장 알맞은 modify 것.  Since any word or phrase modifying a noun always comes before the noun in Korean, there can be two phrases like these modifying the same noun..  Another example:  나라를 구한 아주 용감한 군인들, where both 나라를 구한 and 아주 용감한 modify 군인들.